# chmod +x command Rollback

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a folder called "website" containing lots of folders and text files  and i ran `chmod +x website` command, then i couldn't save the changes which made on the text files in that folder with reason `Couldn't save changes of this file 'permission denied'` so How could i reverse this command to be able to make changes on the files as normal user?
I'm using fedora workstation 25.
Thank you.

Comment: are you sure you were able to edit them before? Are you sure you made no other changes? Maybe you ran `chmod =x website`?

Answer (score 5):

`chmod +x website` will only add the execution flag to the directory for all users, thereby allowing all users to enter the directory. It will not change any write permission.

I believe you are trying to change files in that directory which are not writable by an unprivileged user. In this case, you have to switch to the root user and try again.

Edit: Almost certainly the execution bit was already set for that directory, so trying to revert the command via `chmod -x website` will likely make matters worse.

Comment: But before this command i was able to change and save changes normally

Comment: Then something else happened.